# ssh-add doesn't work since installing TortoiseGIT

Tags: git, ssh, tortoisegit

I was a happy user of git on Windows 7 64-bits, with a happy .bashrc script copied from github or bitbucket, until I had the terrible idea of installing TortoiseGIT.

Immediately ssh-add started failing and it no longer adds my credentials, so I have to type my passphrase all the time.

I always get same the error when I run ssh-add or when I type my passphrase during a pull or push. *Git still works fine, albeit the error*.

> **Error reading response length from authentication socket.**

I have installed and uninstalled git and TortoiseGIT multiple times, searched the registry, environment variables and configuration files without success. Help is highly appreciated.

Comment: On a side note, I think TortoiseGit is a ***terrible*** GUI client for Git. It's heavily influenced by TortoiseSVN, and has too many SVN-style workflows and tools in it. I actually don't recommend git GUIs at all, because I think they abstract away too much understanding of how git actually works. But if you ***must*** use a GUI, then I recommend [SourceTree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) instead of TortoiseGit, because  its tools are more git-centric.

Comment: Did you choose TortoisePlink or OpenSSH when installing TortoiseGit?

Comment: @Cupcake: I know! But I saw a nice chart of someone else's repo and I wondered how mine looked like. I actually never intended to use it to replace the command prompt. But thanks for the tip!

Comment: @linquize: I chose OpenSSH every time I installed TortoiseGIT because I already had that nice ssh-add script working, even though in theory Putty integrates better with Windows. I'm starting to think the only way to fix this is to get rid of my profile, which will be a major **pain**.